# Microsoft Graph and GET boards from Delve

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, delve

As Office Graph (GQL) is being deprecated in a month's time, I'm making the shift to Microsoft Graph.

I want to query the graph to get a list of Delve board and this was easy to do with Office Graph (with jQuery ajax calls).

```
https://<tenant_address>//_api/search/query?querytext='Path:TAG://PUBLIC/?NAME=*'&Properties='IncludeExternalContent:true,GraphQuery:ACTOR(ME)'
```

Unfortunately, I don't see any endpoints in Microsoft Graph that supports retrieving said boards. I've used the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) that Microsoft provides, but can't get any Delve action going. Does anyone have any idea for how to query Delve or a workaround?

For those wondering, the Delve boards are 
located on the bottom left of your Delve page:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's currently no replacement for working with Delve Boards exposed in Microsoft Graph. Could raise this as a suggestion on the Delve UserVoice? https://delve.uservoice.com The product team will have a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the confirmation of my suspicions.

For those that also encounter this problem, please support this suggest [here on Delve Uservoice](https://delve.uservoice.com/forums/219594-support/suggestions/20387824-microsoft-graph-endpoints-to-delve-boards-delve-in).